# How to disable Data Usage Cycle's autoreset

Tags: settings, mobile-data

I'm using a prepaid card and there's no billing cycle.

How can I disable the data usage tracker from auto-resetting?

Answer (score 1):

As of `Android Oreo` you cannot disable the billing cycle from the `Settings`. However, there is an application, which monitors all the data you use, but unfortunately, recently it became `Samsung` exclusive. I'm talking about [Samsung Max](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.opera.max.global) (previously known as Opera Max). I've tried other apps for mobile data monitoring, but only this one could show a custom cycle. If you don't own a `Samsung` you can try the Play Store for apps, which also offer the monitoring you're looking for, and share your results here :)

Comment: I'm using official Pixel 2. Any idea what's a good solution? Assumption of cycles is a pretty tard move really.

Comment: @Pacerier I'm with the Pixel XL and [this](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.roysolberg.android.datacounter) app does pretty good job for tracking the data usage. It has the options to display data for all time or since interface start up, which I think is what you're looking for.